# How Can I Get Value of This Cell without Formulas in LibreOffice Macros

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I work on LibreOffice Macro, I work aboout copy-paste macro. I could write my macro but I have a problem.

When I wrote it, it paste with its formulas but I don't want to copy with formulas.

I must write it with their coordinate because of my for loop.

Here is my code:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub CopyPaste

rA = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress")
cA = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.table.CellAddress")  

For iCount6 = 1 to 5


With rA
  .Sheet       = 0
  .StartColumn = 1
  .StartRow    = iCount6
  .EndColumn   = 1
  .EndRow      = iCount6

End With
With cA
  .Sheet       = 0
  .Column      = 3
  .Row         = iCount6
End With
ThisComponent.Sheets(0).CopyRange(cA, rA)

next iCount6

End Sub
```

How can I do it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

to copy a range try this code

```
sub copyRange
    Dim arr()
    Doc = ThisComponent
    sh = Doc.currentcontroller.activesheet
    RangeToCopy = sh.getCellRangeByName("A3:D7")
    arr = RangeToCopy.getDataArray
    RangeTarget = sh.getCellRangeByName("A10:D14")
    RangeTarget.setDataArray(arr)
End Sub
```